# Triggering 2nd Azure Pipeline After Successful Run on 1st pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two Azure pipelines, A and B. I'm aiming to have pipeline B execute whenever pipeline A completes successfully, but I also want pipeline B to be triggered independently based on its own criteria. My second pipeline, B, is defined as follows:

```html
trigger:
  - master
pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: mySourcePipeline
      source: Source Pipeline
      trigger: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    lfs: true

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: echo 'Second pipeline is triggered'
```

I'm following the guidance provided here: [Azure Pipelines Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops).

However, in my scenario, pipeline A completes successfully, yet the second pipeline (B) doesn't get triggered. What might be causing this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**What I'm aiming for is:
The initial pipeline for setting up Azure infrastructure, including items like storage accounts and resource groups.
The second pipeline to handle deploying and publishing content to the newly created storage account.
The second pipeline, which will not only be triggered after the first one but also have its independent trigger. This means it can be initiated on its own apart from its connection to the first pipeline.**

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that first pipeline looks like

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - staging
    - production
variables:
- name: isProduction
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
- name: isStaging
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "isProduction: $(isProduction)"
        echo "isStaging: $(isStaging)"
        echo "Build.SourceBranch $(Build.SourceBranch)"
```

And it is named `firstpipeline` (not the yaml file, but the name of the pipeline in Azure Devops portal).

Then your secondary pipeline should look like

```yaml
trigger:
- staging
- production

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: firstpipeline   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: firstpipeline       # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include:
        - staging
        - production
variables:
  - name: isProduction
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "isProduction: $(isProduction)"
        echo "isStaging: $(isStaging)"
        echo "Build.SourceBranch $(Build.SourceBranch)"
```

So as a source you should use name of the pipeline not the yaml file.

You can find this here on [github](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-manual/tree/master/stackoverflow/103-dependent-trigger)

Comment: In this solution is secondPipeline runs after Success of firstPipeline? or runs parallel to it? and without depending to first's result? and if first's triggers changed ...

Comment: If commit change to `production` branch it will trigger `firstpipeline `and `contentpipeline` because both have trigger on `production` branch - this would be in parallel. But it also trigger contentpipeline once again after firstpipeline finishes.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej 
"Can we conditionally trigger the pipeline, such as when changes occur exclusively within the 'deployment/*' folder, similar to the way we specify triggers in the following configuration?"

  paths:
    include:
      - app/packages/x-x/*
How can I add the same bellow ?

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: X Frontend - Deployment
      source: X Frontend - Deployment # Name of the triggering pipeline
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - staging

Comment: Just to make sure I understood you. You want to have first in the dependent workflow based on the path for the original workflow?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I'd like to activate the second pipeline exclusively only when there are code modifications within the infrastructure folder. In a similar manner to the trigger configuration 
trigger->paths->include-> 'app/packages/x-package/*'...